# Bootstrap collapse pushes anchor point and carousel control

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I am building a portfolio page using bootstrap,

[My Page](http://www.halycon-studios.com/johana/)

I added collapse boxes under every carousel for more info, but when I active the collapsed items , two problem appears

1. Anchor points are not working properly anymore. I set the anchor points to ID's of each div, and the links are in "List" dropdown menu, when the collapses are active, the anchor offset is different somehow, doesn't' take you to 0 point of each div.
2. The carousel controls are not centered anymore, specially when the browser width is getting less

Comment: add `overflow:hidden` in `.eachitem` class, it will fix your `carousel-control` alignment issue.

Comment: Couldn't get your `anchor points not working..` issue

Comment: Thank you, overflow fixed the carousel-control problem. About the anchor points, I set the anchor points to ID's of each div, and the links are in "List" dropdown menu, when the collapses are active, the anchor offset is different somehow, doesn't' take you to 0 point of each div.

Comment: Buddy, the last image isn't visible. but i would suggest replace `margin-top:` with `padding-top:` inside `.eachitem`, so it may work. I'm not sure but worth a try.

Comment: wow, tnx buddy, worked like a charm!!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I have posted it as an answer below. You can mark it as Answer and close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the comments and adding it as an answer.

```
.eachitem {
overflow: hidden; 
padding-top: 100px; /* replace your margin-top with padding-top */
.....
.....
}
```